# ObjectMapper Swift Displays 0.0 for Float var that is not Multiply of 0.5

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

I've been scratching my head over this strange issue.

Basically,

I tested my API and confirmed that it returns a company object like such {.., "averageRating": 4.6}

Im using ObjectMapper

My model file:

```
class Company: Object, Mappable {

    dynamic var averageRating: Float = 0.0

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        averageRating <- map["averageRating"]

     }
```

So The issue when the averageRating from API gives 4.6 (or any number that does not end with .0 or .5) will display as 0.0

When i change the value from my database, to 4.5, it shows up 4.5, no code changes.

What can be the issue here?